# Not able to extract SAP Data into .xlsx format

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui, sap-erp

I am trying to extract data from FB04 T-Code from SAP, but I am not able to extract data to .xlsx format.
my code fails at extracting data and getting error as "The control could not be be found by id.", kindly assist where i am going wrong.

[image]

```
Sub Execute()

Dim base As Worksheet
Set base = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Baseline")

If Not IsObject(SAP_applic) Then
            Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
            Set SAP_applic = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
        End If
            Set Connection = SAP_applic.Children(0)
        If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
            Set Connection = Application.Children(0)
        End If

        If Not IsObject(Session) Then
            Set Session = Connection.Children(0)
        End If
        If IsObject(WScript) Then
            WScript.ConnectObject Session, "on"
            WScript.ConnectObject Application, "on"
        End If


 Session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
 Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "fb04"
 Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
 Session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[3]/menu[0]").Select
 Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBUKRS-LOW").Text = "us11"
 Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBUKRS-HIGH").Text = "us29"
 Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtPBS_APAX").Text = "2"
 Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBLART-LOW").SetFocus
 Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBLART-LOW").caretPosition = 0
 Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btn%_BLART_%_APP_%-VALU_PUSH").press
 Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,0]").Text = "RV"
 Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,1]").Text = "RX"
 Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,2]").Text = "DZ"
 Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,3]").Text = "AB"
 Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,4]").Text = "DA"
 Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,4]").SetFocus
 Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,4]").caretPosition = 2
 Session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
 Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtDATUM-LOW").Text = base.Range("B1")
 Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtDATUM-HIGH").Text = base.Range("B2")
 Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press


 Session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[1]/menu[1]").Select
 Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/radRB_OTHERS").SetFocus
 Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/radRB_OTHERS").Select
 Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cmbG_LISTBOX").Key = "10"
 Session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
 Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxt[0]").Text = "C:\Users\INNICP\Desktop\Baseline 
 Reporting"
 Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxt[1]").Text = "Baseline Report.XLSX"
 Session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press 

 End Sub
```

Comment: I haven’t got an environment to test it in, but I recall that the field you are trying to load the data into doesn’t exist on this page. Is this exactly as recorded? Has anything changed?

Comment: Your script fills the SAP dialogbox for saving a file to disk but it might be that now the windows native dialog box is displayed. If this is the case your script will fail.

Comment: Is there any alternative method to record the script ?